# Java Connection.setClientInfo results AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

It is simple Java code that sets client information (ClientHostname) to `java.sql.Connection`. But it is giving `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.setClientInfo(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V` error. Any one has any idea what went wrong? I am using java 8.

I could not find the route cause for this. Casting to `DB2Connection` also did not help.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://host:port/db", "user", "pwd");
      con.setClientInfo("ClientHostname", "localhost"); // => error here
      System.out.println("SUCCEED  setting ClientHostname");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This method exists since Java 6, but your JDBC driver was apparently made before that, and doesn't have that method yet. Either it's outdated and you should switch to a more recent version, or IBM hasn't provided an up-to-date driver for a very long time, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setClientInfo` is a JDBC 4.0 method, so you need to be using the JDBC 4.0 driver.

IBM provides a JDBC 3.0 driver in `db2jcc.jar`, and JDBC 4.0 driver in `db2jcc4.jar`.  So, make sure you have `db2jcc4.jar` in your `CLASSPATH` and not `db2jcc.jar`.

Comment: oh.. let me check that.

Comment: Error not seen after upgrading the driver to version 4.